# Is it good practice to return an IEnumerable<T> for a collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Writing another question for SO, I came to a pattern that I use very often and I never really reflected about. But now, I’m no longer sure if this is the right way:

If I have collections that my WPF-controls will bind to, I returned almost always `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. However internally , this is in most cases an `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<SomeType>`. I never had a problem with this and all consuming controls always updated correctly, what is not astonishing because they check for the `INotifyCollectionChanged`-interface.

But my question is now, if this is bad practice to declare in the signature only the `IEnumerable<SomeType>` but to return (and also depend on) something much more powerful (`INotifyCollectionChanged`).

**Update:**

I try to clarify:

My main intention is to return an `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. But most of the time, the returned `IEnumerable<SomeType>` implements also `INotifyCollectionChanged` such as `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<SomeType>` does. The consuming controls bind accordingly (what my second intention is).

Maybe I should have asked: Is there an interface that exactly contains IEnumerable and INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. Some sample code to show the pattern you're referring to would be helpful.

Comment: I have well understood the question. I often do the same with List<>.

Comment: Very late, but I've been doing this for years, but today came across a case the broke it :- I have a property declared as IEnumerable<T>, backed by an ObservableCollection<T>.

Strangely, the bound control (a data grid) fails to notice when items are added to the collection, so presumably isn't receiving notifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, `IEnumerable<T>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` are both interfaces - they aren't a definitive type.  You can design your concrete class to implement both, with no problems.  Your API can return the appropriate interface for the method call.  This is, in fact, a good design - not something to avoid.

[`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) does this (indirectly via [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)), and also implements `IList<T>` as well as other interfaces.

If you are making your own custom collection, and plan to use it with data binding, I would make it implement `IEnumerable<T>` (or potentially `IList<T>`, if appropriate) and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  This will give it the best usability, both from code, but also for efficient binding.

---

> (and also depend on)

However, depending on an interface to exist that isn't part of the API is bad practice.  This is dangerous, and part of the reason to return an interface instead of a concrete type is to allow the implementation to change later.  By putting a dependency on an interface that isn't declared, you're making your code fragile.

That being said, I often do what you're attempting, but it's not a "hard" dependency.  Rather, I use `IEnumerable<T>`, and *check for* `INotifyCollectionChanged` - taking advantage of it if it is implemented.  I do, however, allow the code to work if the "secondary" interface doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a minimal interface instead of a richer one is often a good idea. If you have a rich interface there are more things to test and the more things that can go wrong. It also means that you will have to always to support all these extra features for the foreseeable future if you want to avoid breaking changes. This makes it harder to modify your implementation later.

However depending on something that isn't guaranteed by the interface is a bad practice. If one day you don't get an `ObservableCollection` but some other type of collection then the code will fail at runtime rather than at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to think that if only `INotifyCollectionChanged` is correct, you don't want to return just an `IEnumerable`  This would be very much like returning `Object` where what you really want is `MemoryStream.`  Sure, you can convert back to the type you need, but what if some one comes along later, see's the return type of `IEnumerable` and writes code that matches that return but does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about WPF's data binding, and then deside what is the best for return, `IEnumerable<T>` or more concrette type. Since WPF uses reflection to determine the best way of how to bind to specified collection, you shouldn't worry about.

Comment: +1 Good point. But the main scenario is WPF-VMs (its not in my BOs), therefore I think I dont should forget. But in the first version of my post I didn't mention that and if WPF would be only one of many scenarios or if it would be in a BO, I find your answer really good.

Answer (score 0):

> if this is bad practice to declare in the signature only the `IEnumerable<SomeType>` but to return (and also depend on) something much more powerful (`INotifyCollectionChanged`)

**The return value type is chosen to allow value consumers to work with the value without unsafe type casting.**

1. If `IEnumerable` is returned then value consumer should not make assumptions whether it is a collection or it is a collection that can change or it is a collection that can change and can notify about it's changes.

The only way to use `IEnumerable` is to enumerate it! There is no way to determine that something changes and it should be enumerated again!

2. If `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` is returned then value consumer is free to assume that it is a collection and it can notify about it's changes.

`ReadOnlyObservableCollection` value consumer can enumerate the collection or can subscribe for change notifications and later enumerate the collection again when notification is received.

**It is good practice to return** some complex collection under `IEnumerable` interface.

**It is bad practice to use** `IEnumerable` as `INotifyPropertyChanged` or  **convert** `IEnumerable` into `INotifyPropertyChanged` or something more complex.

> Is there an interface that exactly contains `IEnumerable` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`

**Unfortunately no such interface**, only class `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`.